# Why is a pointer using more memory than a variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I thought pointers were supposed to help a program be more memory efficient. I don't understand why the "X" pointer is taking up more space than the "Y" variable. I'm running this program on a 64-bit Windows computer. Take a look at this simple program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Creating new int
    int *X = new int; *X = 2000000000;
    cout << sizeof(X) << ", " << sizeof(*X) << endl;

    // Deleting the new int
    delete x;
    cout << sizeof(X) << ", " << sizeof(*X) << endl;

    // Using a simple variable
    int Y = 2000000000;
    cout << sizeof(Y);
}
```

Here is the output I get:
    (8, 4),
    (8, 4),
    and 4.

Can someone please give an example of how a pointer actually helped save memory?

Comment: Where did you learn that pointer are to help save memory? Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: "I thought pointers were supposed to help a program be more memory efficient." - you thought wrong, pointers have nothing to do with "memory efficiency".

Comment: Why do you believe that pointers help a program's memory footprint? Their goal is to point at things, that's all. On a 64-bit system, that makes them 8 bytes to be able to span the whole address space.

Comment: "Why is a pointer using more memory than a variable?" - A pointer *is* a variable. It's a variable containing an address of something else (it's *pointing to* something else).

Comment: I'm not sure where this coming from, pointers (and references) may indeed help to save a lot of memory when used to pass large stuff around instead of passing that stuff by value.

Comment: "_I thought pointers were supposed to help a program be more memory efficient._" How? When you are using `int Y;`, your program needs to allocate memory only for `int`. When you are using `int *X = new int;`, your program needs to allocate memory for `int`, **and** for `int*`, to refer to said `int`. So, I fail to see how "using pointers can help program be more efficient".

Comment: I suspect that you read or heard that pointers _assist in memory management_.  That is true, but they don't typically assist _by using less memory_.

Comment: Compared to pass-by-value, a formal parameter passed by-const-ref (or const-pointer) avoids the creation of a copy.  When the formal parameter is 'large', this saves both time and space.  Yes, a pointer can save (automatic) memory!

Comment: Imagine your 'main()' created and filled a dynamic memory object, "BigObj* BOdata", that occupied more than half of your system dynamic memory.  Even 'BOdata',  passed by const reference (i.e.  foo( *BOdata) ), will save time, and enough dynamic memory to avoid the memory overflow (and/or perhaps a swap partition thrashing).

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please give an example of how a pointer actually helped save memory?

It actually did not help save you memory at all. There is no reason to assume that it should have saved memory.

> Why is a pointer using more memory than a variable?

A variable uses (at least) as much memory as its type requires. The size of a type depends on how many different states it needs to be able to represent.

For example, the size of `int` must be at least 16 bits in order to represent all the integers that it is required to represent according to the language rules. A pointer on the other hand must be large enough to be able to point any object of the corresponding type in any memory address (in which such object could be located). On a typical modern system, data pointers usually have the same size as the word size of the processor.

In conclusion: A pointer variable may be larger than a non-pointer variable because different types have different memory needs, and some types don't need to be able to represent as many different states as a pointer might need to represent. Your example demonstrates that `int` is such type on your system.

Comment: See also formal parameter vs actual parameter, and pass-by-const-pointer, pass-by-const-ref, vs pass-by-value.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial example of a typical situation where pointers may help to save memory would be passing stuff around. Some function may need to access some large object. In this case passing object itself will create a copy of that object doubling amount of memory used by the first object.

```
  struct Large{ char m_buf[1000]; };

  void foo(Large large) {}

  int main()
  {
        Large large{}; // allocates at least sizeof(Large) bytes ~ 1000 bytes
        foo(large); // allocates at least sizeof(Large) bytes again ~ 1000 bytes
  }
```

Passing a pointer to object will only increase memory consumption by the size of the pointer. Moreover it allows function to modify original object instead of a copy.

```
  void foo(Large * p_large) {}

  int main()
  {
        Large large{}; // allocates at least sizeof(Large) bytes ~ 1000 bytes 
        foo(&large); // allocates at least sizeof(Large *) bytes ~ typically 4 or 8 bytes
  }
```

C++ also offers a safer alternative to a pointer - reference.

Answer (score -2):

Strictly speaking, a pointer is a variable that needs to store an address. The pointer needs an appropriate length to store the address in question. An address has a length that is required to fit. But a variable can also have different length depending on type, *including pointers*. In other words, while each type has a specific range of values it needs to contain,a pointer needs to be able to contain the address.

One example where passing a pointer saves space is in contiguous memory (ie a primitive array). If you know you have 100 integers next to each other, you only need to pass around the address to the first one.

Comment: Pointers can also have different sizes. For example pointers to members versus pointers to non-members. And historically, different sized pointers used with different memory models.

Comment: Even `char*` and `int*` can have different sizes.

Comment: How is that an answer to the question?

Comment: @SergeyA, I updated my answer to try to be more clear. If you think you can improve it, you're free to edit it :)

Comment: @Daniel You are aware of array decaying, are you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, yes an array decays into a pointer when passed around for that reason. Were you to push every element of the array onto the stack it'd be less efficient.